# PHP Web Service session persistence

Tags: php, session, nusoap

I have a web service created in php 5.5 with nusoap it has two functions named as login and getInstances, the first has as input parameters to user and password and if the parameters are correct the function returns a session_id. Until this point all is correct, the session was opened and the id is returned but the problem appears when the same client that consumes the login done a request of getInstance function because now the previously opened session is doesn't exist anymore.

What can I do for keeping persistence session in each request?

I'm sorry for my english.

```
nusoap Web Service

require_once("FunctionsWS.php");

$server = new nusoap_server();
$server->configureWSDL('Servicios Web de CSDocs', 'urn:ecm');

$server->wsdl->addComplexType(  'loginRequest', 
                                'complexType', 
                                'struct', 
                                'all', 
                                '',
                                array('idInstance' => array('name' => 'idInstance', 'type' => 'xsd:integer'),
                                      'instanceName' => array('name' => 'instanceName', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
                                      'userName'   => array('name' => 'userName','type' => 'xsd:string'),
                                      'password'    => array('name' => 'password','type' => 'xsd:string')
                                )
);

$server->wsdl->addComplexType(  'loginReponse', 
                                'complexType', 
                                'struct', 
                                'all', 
                                '',
                                array('idSession'   => array('name' => 'idSession','type' => 'xsd:string'),
                                      'error'   => array('name' => 'error','type' => 'xsd:string'),
                                      'noAccess'   => array('name' => 'noAccess','type' => 'xsd:string'),
                                      'message'   => array('name' => 'message','type' => 'xsd:string')
                                )
);
$server->register(  'login', 
                    array('loginRequest' => 'tns:loginRequest'), // parametros de entrada
                    array('loginReponse' => 'tns:loginReponse'), // parametros de salida
                    'urn:ecm', // namespace
                    'urn:login', // soapaction 
                    'rpc', // style
                    'encoded', // use
                    'Inicio de sesión dentro del sistema CSDocs' // documentation
);

$server->wsdl->addComplexType(  'instanceData', 
                                'complexType', 
                                'struct', 
                                'all', 
                                '',
                                array('idInstance'   => array('name' => 'idInstance','type' => 'xsd:integer'),
                                      'instanceName'   => array('name' => 'instanceName','type' => 'xsd:string'),
                                    'message' => array('name'=>'message', 'type'=>'xsd:string')
                                )
);

$server->wsdl->addComplexType('instanceList',
                              'complexType',
                              'array',
                              '',
                              'SOAP-ENC:Array',
                              array(),
                              array(
                                  array(
                                      'ref' => 'SOAP-ENC:arrayType',
                                      'wsdl:arrayType' => 'tns:instanceData[]'
                                  )
                              ),
                              "tns:instanceData"
);

$server->register(  'getInstances', // nombre del metodo o funcion
                    array(), // parametros de entrada
                    array('instanceList' => 'tns:instanceList'), // parametros de salida
                    'urn:ecm', // namespace
                    'urn:getInstances', // soapaction debe ir asociado al nombre del metodo
                    'rpc', // style
                    'encoded', // use
                    'Retorna el registro de instancias dadas de alta en el sistema' // documentation
);
```

File with WebService functions

```
    $RoutFile = dirname(getcwd());        

    require_once "$RoutFile/php/Session.php";
    require_once("$RoutFile/php/DataBase.php");
    require_once("$RoutFile/php/Enterprise.php");
    require_once ("$RoutFile/php/Login.php");

function login($data)
{

    if(!isset($_SESSION))
        session_start();

    $login = new Login();
    $session = new Session();

    if(!isset($data['idInstance']))
        return array("error"=>"idInstance no encontrado.");
    if(!isset($data['instanceName']))
        return array('error'=>'instanceName no encontrado.');
    if(!isset($data['userName']))
        return array('error'=>'userName no encontrado.');

    /*Se comprueba si existía una sesión activa  */
    $idSession = $session->getIdSession();

    $userData = array();

    if($idSession!=null){
        $userData = $session->getSessionParameters ();
    }else{
        $idInstance = $data['idInstance'];
        $instanceName = $data['instanceName'];
        $userName = $data['userName'];
        $password = $data['password'];

        $userData = $login->searchRegisterUser($instanceName, $userName, $password);

    }

    if(!is_array($userData))
            return array("error" => $userData);
        if(count($userData)==0)
            return array("noAccess" => "Acceso denegado. Compruebe que tiene permisos para entrar al sistema al igual que su usuario o contraseña sean correctos");


    if(is_array($userData)){
        $text = '';
        if(isset($userData['IdUsuario']))
            $text.= $userData['IdUsuario'];
        if(isset($userData['Login']))
            $text.= $userData['Login'];
        if(isset($userData['IdGrupo']))
            $text.= $userData['IdGrupo'];
        if(isset($userData['Nombre']))
            $text.= $userData['Nombre'];

//        return array('error'=>"($idInstance, $instanceName,". $text);
        $idSession = $session->createSession($idInstance, $instanceName, $userData['IdUsuario'], $userData['Login'], $userData['IdGrupo'], $userData['Nombre']);


        return array('idSession'=>$idSession);  //return session_id to the client

    }
    else
        return array("error"=>"Usuario o contraseña incorrectos");  
}

function getInstances()
{
    $DB = new DataBase();
    $data = array();

    $QueryInstances = "SELECT *FROM instancias";

    $ResultQuery = $DB->ConsultaSelect("cs-docs", $QueryInstances);

    if($ResultQuery['Estado']!=1)
    {
        $data[] = array("message" => "Error inesperado: ".$ResultQuery['Estado']);
        return $data;
    }

    if(count($ResultQuery['ArrayDatos'])==0)
        $data[] = array("idInstance"=>0, "instanceName"=>"No existen instancias");

    for($cont = 0; $cont < count($ResultQuery['ArrayDatos']); $cont++){

        $idInstance = $ResultQuery['ArrayDatos'][$cont]['IdInstancia'];
        $instanceName = $ResultQuery['ArrayDatos'][$cont]['NombreInstancia'];

        $data[] = array("idInstance"=>$idInstance, "instanceName"=>$instanceName);

    }

    return $data;
}
```